# Connect to MySQL via OLEDB

Tags: c#, mysql, oledbconnection

I need to connect my app to MySQL via OLEDB. I wrote this:

```
oleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection();
oleDbConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=MySQLProv; Data Source=myHostName; Initial Catalog=dmz_storage; User ID=myUserName; Password=myPassword;";
oleDbConnection.Open();
```

But I get an exception: Provider MySQLProv is not registered at the local computer. Of course, I add MySQL.Data.dll to my project. So how can I register MySQLProv? Or can I actually connect to MySQL via OLEDB?

Comment: "...I add MySQL.Data.dll..." - how?  Did you just add a reference, or did you install a nuget package?

Comment: Also, OleDbConnection is very old school (and potentially an unsafe minefield).  Take a look at EntityFramework for heavyweight work, or Dapper for something more light.

Comment: hmm, I install MySQL Connector, then "just add a reference"

Comment: MySql.Data.dll used for MySQL Connector .NET. If you want OLE DB connection, you need to register OLE DB provider name first.

Comment: @Neil, I need in OLEDB

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, how? That was my question.

Comment: @Neil Those frameworks build on-top of ADO.NET, which includes OleDBConnection. I strongly disagree with your assessment that it's "a minefield". Though OdbcConnection should be preferred over OleDBConnection where possible given Microsoft has almost-but-not-quite deprecated OLE-DB and augmented ODBC instead.

Comment: @ИванКозлов there's no OLEDB provider for MySQL. What you added is the *.NET* provider. There's also an ODBC provider that you can use through OlEDB

Comment: @Neil `OleDbConnection is very old school (and potentially an unsafe minefield`. No. Just No. On both

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I can connect via ODBC, connection string is `Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 UNICODE Driver};Data Source=myHost; User=myname;Password=myPass; Database = dmz_storage; Option=3;`, but how can I use those driver to connect via OLEDB?

Comment: @ИванКозлов first, *why*? You already have the .NET libraries, why use ODBC? Second, MySQL doesn't have an OLEDB provider. Period. You'd have to buy one from a third party. You can use `OdbcConnection` to connect directly throught ODBC. If you insist on using the OleDB classes (again, WHY?) you'll have to use the [OleDB to ODBC provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-odbc?view=sql-server-2017), ie `"Provider=MSDASQL;DSN=dsnName;UID=MyUserID;PWD=MyPassword;"`

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, I need to add a connection string as a parameter to other closed app that can work only with OLEDB

Comment: @ИванКозлов the official MySQL providers [are here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/). There's no OLEDB or MySQLProv. Did you try to copy some old connection string perhaps? MySQL did offer an OLEDB provider 10 years  ago but that's so far in the past that only a few forum posts will mention this.

Comment: @ИванКозлов then use the OLEDB to ODBC provider. Or buy a third-party provider

Comment: The minefield of 'low-level' sql queries is my concern.  In my experience, once you start at this low level, you end up creating SQL queries by adding strings together.  If you start at a higher abstraction, you are more likely to be both type-safe and sql-injection safe.

Comment: @Neil this has nothing at all to do with OLEDB and statistically, it's FAR FAR FAR more likely to occur with ODBC. Not because ODBC isn't safe but because those guilty of string concatenation are mainly PHP developers. Older PHP libraries didn't have parameters. Parameterized queries were available even in VB6, which used OLEDB. Correlation isn't causation though and SQL Injection doesn't mean ODBC is unsafe

Comment: @Neil besides, the lower level protocol is ODBC, not OLEDB. Both were created by Microsoft. ODBC is the older, C-style API. OLEDB is the newer, object-oriented API. *Queries* are executed at the highest abstraction level though, where it doesn't matter which protocol the provider uses

Comment: All I'm saying, is that, if I was looking over someone's shoulder and saw they were starting to write a web server in C, I would point them in the direction of ASP.NET, rather than the HTTP documentation.